# Divergence of a Cross Product vs Vector Algebra Identity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

The divergence of a cross product can be written with the following identity:
$$ \nabla \cdot (\vec{F} \times \vec{G}) = \vec{G} \cdot (\nabla \times \vec{F}) - \vec{G} \cdot (\nabla \times \vec{F}) $$
But there is also an identity for a tripple product of vectors:
$$ \vec{a} \cdot (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) = \vec{b} \cdot (\vec{c} \times \vec{a}) = \vec{c} \cdot (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) 
$$
I was wondering, since if you applied this second identity to the first, the frist would seemingly become $0$? Surely I am making a mistake somehow. I apologize if this is a bad question, all answers are appreciated.

Comment: $\nabla$ is an operator, to get a clae idea what's happening here, see the proof of tipple product of vectors and divergence of cross product

Comment: It has to do with whether the components of different vectors commute. Since $\nabla$ is an operator it doesn't in general commute with the compontents of $\vec F$ and $\vec G$.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you that makes sense, I guess since $\nabla$ is not a real vector, it also doesn't make sense to take the triple product as a volume.